# Is there a way to see which scripts run on startup?

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd

I am trying to find the startup scripts and everything I can find has me looking at the .service files in /etc/systemd/system .

Does that mean that every .service file within that directory is a startup script or is there a way to list only the startup scripts?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/795226/158442

Comment: Note that your operating system _does not have_ startup scripts.  This is one of the things that the designers of this part of the operating system have explicitly changed (one of them famously writing about it as a removal of "shell script infestation of the boot process").  Unit files are not scripts.  They are not interpreted programs in an imperative programming language.

Answer (score 1):

> systemd is the default init framework, replacing initscripts. The services which are started by systemd can be found in the subfolders of /etc/systemd/system/

This is what [archwiki says](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autostarting), so yes. There are also graphical tools for that, again, consult the wiki.

Comment: Is there a way of telling which services are enabled upon startup and which are not?

Comment: `initctl list` is standard command.

Comment: in  /etc/systemd/system/ i found my startup service.